# How do I get the complete path of the file?

Tags: java, file, servlets, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the file path from HTML input form in Firefox 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3)

Is there any way I can get the complete path of the file from the `input file tag` without using the 3rd party API ?

```
<form method="post" action="SendTheFileName">
                <div id="Files_to_be_shared"> 
                      <input type="file" id="File" name="FileTag" />
                      <input type="submit" value="Share" /> 
               </div>
 </form>
```

*Snippet from the servlet :*

```
String fileName = request.getParameter("FileTag");
```

What I get now from the above java code is just the name of the file selected. How do I get the complete path of the file ?

Comment: *"How do I get the complete path of the file ?"*  The full path is none of your web-apps. business, is the general view.

Comment: @AndrewThompson None of my web-apps business ? ! I need it.

Comment: No, you actually need the file contents. See also the duplicate link.

Comment: @BalusC No. I only need to know the file name and its path. I do not need the contents. I am not asking how to upload a file

Comment: Well, then a web application is the wrong tool for the job. Perhaps you need an applet or flash application. It all depends on the concrete functional requirements which still sounds very strange.

Comment: @BalusC why do you say a wrong tool ? I think I can easily get the complete path using apache commons lib using the web app. I wanted to know if it can be done without it..I mean the JDK

Comment: Oh, you've thus not read the duplicate link. Well, then it ends here.

Comment: @BalusC I read the answers. Thank you for the link. Let me describe my situation:A client shares a file. That file name is then sent to the server database.All other clients can see the file names, that a particular client has shared. To get that file,other client connects to that client. Client also acts as a server at the same time and other clients are able to connect to that client that might have an address like :`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app/list`. If i know the full file path, the other user will be able to download the file.

Comment: For that P2P/Torrent protocols are invented and proven to be much more efficient. HTTP/HTML doesn't support this. If you've really a hard head in; in web development terms, you're better off with embedding a client application (Applet, Silverlight, etc) in a web page. If Applet (Swing), you can get full path with `JFileChooser`. In the end, a desktop applicaiton like as whatever BitTorrent/uTorrent/Emule are doing is much more elegant.

Comment: @BalusC _"HTTP protocol doesn't support this"_ I won't be able to make a connection to a node that has its server running ? If I make a connection I won't be able to download the file ?

Comment: Let's say, it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: By the way, if your users are still browsing with IE (not sure about the last versions), then you'll get the full path of their uploaded files from a simple call to `request.getParameter("FileTag")`. Because that's what IE sends, instead of the single filename...

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered in other threads, I think that any of this 2 can help you:

[How to get full path using <input id="file" name="file" type="file" size="60" > in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955832/how-to-get-full-path-using-input-id-file-name-file-type-file-size-60)

[How to get full path of file using input type file in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244256/how-to-get-full-path-of-file-using-input-type-file-in-javascript)

Just to complete my answer a bit more and since you added the java tag to it, here I will include you a little snippet of code that shows some of the most common information you can get out of a file, but from the java perspective:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FilePaths {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String[] fileArray = { 
                "C:\\projects\\workspace\\testing\\f1\\f2\\f3\\file5.txt", 
                "folder/file3.txt",
                "../testing/file1.txt", 
                "../testing", 
                "f1/f2"
        };

        for (String f : fileArray) {
            displayInfo(f);
        }

    }

    public static void displayInfo(String f) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(f);
        System.out.println("========================================");
        System.out.println("          name:" + file.getName());
        System.out.println("  is directory:" + file.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("        exists:" + file.exists());
        System.out.println("          path:" + file.getPath());
        System.out.println(" absolute file:" + file.getAbsoluteFile());
        System.out.println(" absolute path:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("canonical file:" + file.getCanonicalFile());
        System.out.println("canonical path:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
    }

}
```